# Conversion of VB6 project to .net- references error?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a VB6 project when i try to tun this it throws some errors like

```
The referenced component 'AxMSCommLib' could not be found.  
The referenced component 'AxOWC' could not be found.    
The referenced component 'ComctlLib' could not be found.    
The referenced component 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' could not be found.
```

and when i remove these references it shows the error where these references are used further like in this line

```
Public WithEvents ProgressBar2 As AxComctlLib.AxProgressBar
```

it says

```
Type 'AxComctlLib.AxProgressBar' is not defined.
```

Facing this situation first time, how to solve this, how to add these references in project or is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Patrik says in a comment, these are all COM object that needs to be registered before they can be used by a development environment (both VB6 and .Net). The error message you get indicates that these files are not registered on your computer.

You need to install the COM object dependencies. Find the original installation package for each dependency and run it. Hint - one of them is Excel. Another one might be the Microsoft Comm control (I forget the exact name).

Some people may advise you to try and register OCXs & DLLs manually, but it's faster to run the install packages, as the OCXs/DLLs may require other things in order to actually work.

Comment: what do you mean by run install packages, how can i do this ? can you please explain a little bit??

Comment: These are all COM object that needs to be registered before they can be used by a development environment (both VB6 and .Net). The error message you get indicates that these files are not registered on your computer. Either you can search for the files and register them manually with regsrv32.exe or you can just rerun the installation packages that installed the files in the first place, the idea here is that the installation package will take care of registering the binaries.

Comment: Good point @PatrikB. I have edited your comment into my answer as an introduction :)

Comment: Sorry @Mogli have you find AxMSCommLib dll? Do you have a link? i  ve the same issue right now. Thanks.